# MS Access - SQL Query for Average of Each Day Data

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate-functions, average

I have a set of data spanning across 3 days. Based on the first column from the left, is it possible to have a query that calculates the average of the values in the third column from the left based on each day?

The end result will be two columns:

```
1/1/2008 | 1.605 
2/1/2008 | 1.59 
3/1/2008 | 1.56
```

I think the logic will be something like in a loop:

- Based on the day in the first column, if it is the same day, count the number of rows and add up the values of the third column
- Use the sum of the values of the third column and divide by the number of rows to get the Average
- day + 1

But how can we implement a loop in MS Access?

Here is the set of data:

[image]

Edit:
If I want to group by the date, where the day is between yesterday's 6PM to today's 6PM?

The `BETWEEN` clause is to check for records that are between yesterday's 18:00:00 and today's 18:00:00. Example, for **1/1/2008**, the record will start from `1/1/2008 6:00PM` to `2/1/2008 6:00PM`. For **2/1/2008**, the record will start from `2/1/2008 6:00PM` to 3/1/2008 6:00PM`. So on and so forth...

I have a code snippet that checks for this:

```
([In process analysis result].[Date Time]) Between Date()-1+#12/30/1899 18:0:0# And Date()+#12/30/1899 18:0:0#)
```

But it only groups for one day before. How can I apply for the set of data?

Edit 2:
This is the query that I have done, but it is still not correct. Any idea what is wrong?

```
SELECT DateValue([Date Time]) As DateValue, Avg([MFR g/10min]) AS [AvgOfMFR g/10min]
FROM [In process analysis result]
WHERE ((([Date Time])>Now()-365) AND (([Operation Grade-Load]) Like "EX*") AND (([Date Time]) Between [Date Time]-1+#12/30/1899 18:0:0# And [Date Time]+#12/30/1899 18:0:0#))
GROUP BY DateValue([Date Time]);
```

Comment: Appreciate any advice on this, please.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT the AVG of the value and GROUP BY the date

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please refer to my edit?

Comment: Sorry haven't been on here much, but if you're still looking for answer...  Quickest answer may be to set up another column (call it absolute date or something), and use a formula to add 6 hours to the date.  That way you could group on that "absolute" date but it's really referring to your time period from 6 hours previous.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks basically correct.  The `where` clause looks off.  Start with this:

```
SELECT DateValue(DateAdd("h", 6, [Date Time])) As DateValue,
       Avg([MFR g/10min]) AS [AvgOfMFR g/10min]
FROM [In process analysis result]
WHERE [Date Time] > DateAdd("yyyy", -1, DateAdd("h", 6, Now())) AND
      [Operation Grade-Load] Like "EX*" 
GROUP BY DateValue(DateAdd("h", 6, [Date Time]));
```

> I'm not sure what the `BETWEEN` condition is supposed to be doing.  If
>   you want a particular date range, just use date constants.

**Edit**: Date/time should be offset by 6 hours as in the above edit. And a proper 1-year-back expression should be used. Not sure if current time should be shifted 6 hours too (shown); if not, just remove the *DateAdd* of Now().

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The `BETWEEN` clause is to check for records that are between yesterday's 18:00:00 and today's 18:00:00. Example, for **1/1/2008**, the record will start from `1/1/2008 6:00PM` to `2/1/2008 6:00PM`. For **2/1/2008**, the record will start from `2/1/2008 6:00PM` to 3/1/2008 6:00PM`. Will it be possible?

Comment: Your _Where_ clause couldn't work. See my edit of the answer from @Gordon.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you for your edit. I am trying to understand the offset of the DateTime. How can I see the values that used to calculate the average? Just trying to verify the results.

Comment: You can't. The time part is cut away, so it is not possible to offset the date back by six hours.

Comment: @Gustav In that case, if the time part is cut away, meaning the average is calculated based on the date? But not based on yesterday's 18:00 to today's 18:00?

Comment: No. The time part is in the calculation but not the display - as it is grouped by the date.

Comment: @Gustav Ah, I see. In that case, it is not what I'm looking out for. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes it is. At least referring to your question.