# MS Access Switch Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate

I have the following SQL statement. However, it is unable to run. It says that:

> Your query does not include the specified expression
>   'DateValue(Switch(Hour([Date Time])>=18 And Hour([Date Time])<22,[Date
>   Time],Hour([Date Time])>=22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=0 And
>   Hour([Date Time])<2,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=2 And Hour([Date
>   Time])<6,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=6 And Hour([Date
>   Time])<10,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=10 And Hour([Date
>   Time])<14,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=14 And Hour([Date
>   Time])<18,[Date Time]-1)) As DateValue' as part of an aggregate
>   function.

```
SELECT DateValue(Switch(Hour([Date Time])>=18 And Hour([Date Time])<22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=0 And Hour([Date Time])<2,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=2 And Hour([Date Time])<6,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=6 And Hour([Date Time])<10,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=10 And Hour([Date Time])<14,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=14 And Hour([Date Time])<18,[Date Time]-1)) As DateValue, Avg([MFR g/10min]) AS Average, Max([MFR g/10min]) - Min([MFR g/10min]) As Difference
FROM [In process analysis result]
GROUP BY DateValue([Date Time]);
```

Is there any clue what is wrong?

Edit 1:
If I run the following query, it will work:

`SELECT DateValue(Switch(Hour([Date Time])>=18 And Hour([Date Time])<22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=0 And Hour([Date Time])<2,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=2 And Hour([Date Time])<6,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=6 And Hour([Date Time])<10,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=10 And Hour([Date Time])<14,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=14 And Hour([Date Time])<18,[Date Time]-1)) AS DateValue, Avg([MFR g/10min]) AS Average, Max([MFR g/10min]) - Min([MFR g/10min]) As Difference
FROM [In process analysis result]
GROUP BY Switch(Hour([Date Time])>=18 And Hour([Date Time])<22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=0 And Hour([Date Time])<2,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=2 And Hour([Date Time])<6,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=6 And Hour([Date Time])<10,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=10 And Hour([Date Time])<14,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=14 And Hour([Date Time])<18,[Date Time]-1);`

However, the results are not what I am looking for. I am trying to group by the date of the column, `DateValue`:

[image]

The DateValue() is not grouped by and I couldn't get the average and difference between the Max and the Min.

Please help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access - SQL Query for Average of Each Day Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581378/ms-access-sql-query-for-average-of-each-day-data)

Comment: You wouldn't offset the DateTime value this way. Study your other question.

Answer (score 0):

your grouping function should be the same as the selection (add: DateValue() to your grouping criteria):

`SELECT DateValue(Switch(Hour([Date Time])>=18 And Hour([Date Time])<22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=0 And Hour([Date Time])<2,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=2 And Hour([Date Time])<6,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=6 And Hour([Date Time])<10,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=10 And Hour([Date Time])<14,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=14 And Hour([Date Time])<18,[Date Time]-1)) AS DateValue, Avg([MFR g/10min]) AS Average, Max([MFR g/10min]) - Min([MFR g/10min]) As Difference
FROM [In process analysis result]
GROUP BY DateValue(Switch(Hour([Date Time])>=18 And Hour([Date Time])<22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=22,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=0 And Hour([Date Time])<2,[Date Time],Hour([Date Time])>=2 And Hour([Date Time])<6,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=6 And Hour([Date Time])<10,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=10 And Hour([Date Time])<14,[Date Time]-1,Hour([Date Time])>=14 And Hour([Date Time])<18,[Date Time]-1));`